# SQL Server connection string for a standard user

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

I am trying to connect to an mdf file using the following connection string:

```
 <add name="ApplicationServices" 
      connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|nzdb.mdf;User Instance=true" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I am a standard Windows user (don't have administrative rights). When I try to connect, I get an error

> Cannot open user default database. Login failed. Login failed for
>   user 'MACHINENAME\USERNAME'.

I have not attached this file to the local SQL Server Express instance assuming that the file will get automatically attached when connecting.

Basically, I am configuring the project such a way that anybody can easily make a copy of the `.mdf` file and start working on it by changing the `web.config` without caring about permission of the user currently logged in because SQL Server Express is running locally.

Please let me know what am I missing. How do I change the connection string such that the application just connects to any `.mdf` pointed by `AttachDBFilename` file. If user credentials are necessary then which user should be used so that the project would work on any machine (users like sa?)

Comment: post your sample connectionstring.

Comment: Thanks. Connection String added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I addressed this issue by setting "User Instance=false" in the connection string.

Thanks.